# Adding some characters to a URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I need your help. I'm working on a file-sharing-area. There i want to provide dynamically a link where people can download their specific file. I thought the easiest way would be to handle it by my htaccess file.

BUT i didn't get the solution yet.

I want to communicate the link:

http://sub.domain.com/fc80d8105e084e7d26c694b4d6f184c1

and it will be changed into:

http://sub.domain.com/transfer/d.php?f4d=fc80d8105e084e7d26c694b4d6f184c1

What is the solution for it?

My idea was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^transfer/d\.php\?f4d([^/]*)$ /?f4d=$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```

But this doesn't work unfortunately.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ transfer/d.php?f4d=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hey Croises! Great this is perfect! thank you! Now everything's working.

Comment: Hi Croises - sorry... hope i've done it right. 'cause i didn't know how to do that. thx